# Installing tensorflow on Anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I have a linux machine to which i installed Anaconda. 
I am following:

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup.html

pip instaltion part.

To be more specific:

```
which python
```

gives

```
/home/user/anaconda2/bin/python
```

After which i entered:

```
export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.10.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

And after:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

However,
while trying:

```
python -c "import tensorflow"
```

I get an import error:

```
ImportError: No module named tensorflow
```

Comment: and that error was?

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'sudo' makes pip install tensorflow outside the env. Try:

pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL

Just tested this on Ubuntu 14.04 w/ conda env, was able to reproduce (with sudo) and resolve issue (without sudo).

You can also check the "Using Conda" section of [tensorflow.org](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup.html#anaconda-installation). They list the below:

```
# Python 2
(tensorflow)$ pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL

# Python 3
(tensorflow)$ pip3 install --ignore-installed --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

Answer (score 0):

In anaconda, simply do:

#### for installation

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

#### for update/upgrade

```
# -f will force the current installation to upgrade
conda update -f -c conda-forge tensorflow
```