# could not find the version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow in python 3.5

Tags: tensorflow, pip, anaconda

I am trying to install tensorflow with the pip in the cmd, but it is appearing an error "could not find the version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow"
I have the python 3.5 version installed and the Anaconda 64bits too. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The 'sudo' makes pip install tensorflow outside the env. Try:

pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL

Just tested this on Ubuntu 14.04 w/ conda env, was able to reproduce (with sudo) and resolve issue (without sudo).

You can also check the "Using Conda" section of tensorflow.org. They list the below:

[1]: [Installing tensorflow on Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39612416/installing-tensorflow-on) anaconda?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this it will work copy this line and paste it in your command line before this make sure python already installed on your computer

pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl